# how to get id the same input value without refresh

Tags: php, ajax

i have input type and button, i need when choose item by click next image by ajax i will get id for this item and put it into input type, and i wont to print this item by using this

```
<input name="print" type="submit" id="print" value="Print" class="css3buttonblue"  onclick="window.open('BillsPrint.php?bills_ID=<?php echo $_POST['bills_ID']?>', '_blank')" />
```

the problem here i canot get id value from input type to `'BillsPrint.php?bills_ID=<?php echo $_POST['bills_ID']?>'`

how can i put the id on this link `BillsPrint.php?bills_ID=<?php echo $_POST['bills_ID']?>` without refresh page

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `this` to access the element itself.
You're using JavaScript anyways, so this should be safe:

```
'BillsPrint.php?bills_ID=<?php echo $_POST['bills_ID']?>&input_id=' + this.id
```

Comment: are you mean `<input name="print" type="submit" id="print" value="Print" class="css3buttonblue"  onclick="window.open('BillsPrint.php?bills_ID='+this.bills_ID, '_blank')" />` i try put id not insert

Comment: `<input name="print" type="submit" id="print" value="Print" class="css3buttonblue" onclick="window.open('BillsPrint.php?bills_ID='+this.id, '_blank')" />`